# I try yo add prev and next function in my app but it keep crashing

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a beginner in android studio, I want to add next and prev function in my media player but the app keep crashing. Everything is working well after I add this function into my app
The music is not displaying and the app keep closing pop out when I try to press any button in my app.
Here is my code. Can anyone please help me? I really appreciate it.

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.SeekBar

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var runnable: Runnable
    private lateinit var handler : Handler // Initialize this
    private lateinit var mediaPlayer : MediaPlayer // Declare MediaPlayer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer)
        val play = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.play)
        val seekbar: SeekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar)
        val next = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.nextBt)
        val previous = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.prevBt)

        val mp3Files = ArrayList<Int>()
        mp3Files.add(R.raw.music1)
        mp3Files.add(R.raw.ifiaintgotyou)

        var currentSongIndex = 0

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer() // Initialize MediaPlayer here

        fun playCurrentSong() {
                mediaPlayer.reset()
                val resourceId = mp3Files[currentSongIndex]

                // Get the resource name based on the resource ID
                val resourceName = resources.getResourceEntryName(resourceId)

                val assetFileDescriptor = assets.openFd(resourceName)
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor, assetFileDescriptor.startOffset, assetFileDescriptor.length)
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare()
                mediaPlayer.start()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }



        fun playNextSong() {
            currentSongIndex = (currentSongIndex + 1) % mp3Files.size
            playCurrentSong()
        }

        fun playPreviousSong() {
            currentSongIndex = (currentSongIndex - 1 + mp3Files.size) % mp3Files.size
            playCurrentSong()
        }

        seekbar.progress = 0

        handler = Handler() // Initialize the handler

        play.setOnClickListener {
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                playCurrentSong()
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause)
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause()
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play)
            }
        }

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress)
                }
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                // Implement if needed
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                // Implement if needed
            }
        })

        runnable = Runnable {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                seekbar.progress = mediaPlayer.currentPosition
            }
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
            play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play)
            seekbar.progress = 0
        }

        next.setOnClickListener {
            playNextSong()
        }

        previous.setOnClickListener {
            playPreviousSong()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mediaPlayer.release()
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the esception with stacktrace from logcat to your question.